# MapKit not getting the right location when ipHone updated to ios 16.3.1

Tags: swift

I am doing a restaurant autocomplete using mapkit, and this was working perfectly before I updated my iphone 14 to 16.3.1 (real device).

Before, it used to show my real location on the mapkit, not it shows me in the middle of new York, because that's the default location I set in case of an error.

The location is allowed on my app.

This is my viewdidLoad

```
locationManager.delegate = self
       
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.requestLocation()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
       
mapView.showsUserLocation = true
       
let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
       
let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchBar.placeholder = "Search for restaurants"
navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
       
resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
       
locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
       
locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self
```

When I print the location, it does show me coordinates in new york.

It also gives me this error:
"Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)""

This error used to occur when I didn't allow location services, but this time I did allow them but it still throws this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to change the default location from NY to none.